# elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'No search context found for id [id_num]')

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-helpers

I am trying to retrieve a large number of documents from an Elasticsearch index, the query to elasticsearch is a simple exists query. The actual number of documents returned by the query is 71790 so in order to process them correctly I am using the helpers `scan` function, `helpers.scan(elastic_search,query=doc, index=index,size=1000, scroll='1d')`. What my script does is to retrieve all the documents that contain a certain field, which I call temporal field, in order to assign the value of that temporal field to the non-temporal field of that same document.

Initially I had a `scroll` time of 25 minutes but as I was getting this error I decided to increase it to 1 day to see if it was really a problem of the scroll time but I still get this error. Obviously the code doesn't take 1 day to run, when it takes about 50k documents to be parsed this error pops up. Everything I find on the internet is that it is due to the scroll time but I have already seen that this is not so because I have set it to 1 day and still the error pops up after about 5 minutes.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error? If you need more information about the node or whatever, feel free to ask for it, I don't know exactly what information I should add.

Thank you all!!!

The specific error is as follows:

````
    for hit in result:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 459, in scan
    body={"scroll_id": scroll_id, "scroll": scroll}, **scroll_kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 84, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1307, in scroll
    "GET", "/_search/scroll", params=params, body=body
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 358, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 257, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 182, in _raise_error
    status_code, error_message, additional_info
elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'No search context found for id [12671416]')```
````

Comment: hey there, I'm having the same problem right now. Did you end up solving it?

Comment: @Avision didn't quite fix it but behavior got better when I increased the timeout parameter

Comment: @avison I have also run into this issue, would be happy to hear about possible solutions.

Comment: I saw a discussion of this indicating that the timeout parameter is key and that the API isn't really meant for using to slowly go through data and process it, but on the other hand it seems that as long as the timeout parameter is long enough it should work. Here's the link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-no-search-context-found-for-id-mean/103316/9

Answer (score 0):

resolving exception when the index is not created yet :

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception'
```

check if the index is created